# Expo-Camera is crashing when i build the application, but it runs perfectly while debugging

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-firebase, expo-camera

[image: Crashh logged in firebase]

I am using expo in react native cli. The versions of library are as below :

```
"expo": "^48.0.0",
"expo-camera": "^13.2.1",
"expo-face-detector": "^12.1.1",
"expo-gl": "^12.0.1",
"expo-modules-core": "^1.2.7",
"npm": "^8.19.3",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-native": "^0.70.10",
```

The camera code i m using is as below:

```
renderCamera = () => (
<Camera
  ref={ref => {
    this.camera = ref;
  }}
  style={{
    height:this.props.potrait?1:80,
    width:this.props.potrait?1:100,
  }}
  type={Camera.Constants.Type.front}
  autoFocus={Camera.Constants.AutoFocus.on}
  faceDetectorSettings={{
    mode: FaceDetector.FaceDetectorMode.accurate,
    detectLandmarks: FaceDetector.FaceDetectorLandmarks.none,
    runClassifications: FaceDetector.FaceDetectorClassifications.all,
    minDetectionInterval: 100,
    tracking: true,
  }}
  onFacesDetected={this.state.canDetectFaces ? this.facesDetected : null}
  onFaceDetectionError={this.onFaceDetectionError}
  onMountError={(err) => Alert.alert(err)}
/>
)

return( 
 <View>
  {this.renderCamera()}
 </View>
)
```

Even if i comment face detector code it crashes in build using ./gradlew assembleRelease